# Is it possible to have AWS to prioritize CF Origin Group origins by country?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup were i want to have 2 S3 buckets serving the exact same data, for redundancy. To have them being served (both) by CloudFront, i created an Origin Group. The Origin Group is the origin for the behavior with higher precedence.

My questions are:

1: Are there any fees for keeping content cached for more than the default 24h ? I assume not because it might be cheaper to store than to transfer data.

2: The origin access inside the group seems to always be the same, respecting the failover sequence (primary origin -> secondary origin -> ...). Is there any possibility to make the origin group be load balanced ? ie, actually pulling from the origin with the lowest latency inside the origin group ? I saw that i can use Lambda@Edge to change the domain for the request. How does that work with conjunction with Origin Groups and failover ? If i have a bucket A and a bucket B and they both form an Origin Group (A primary, B secondary) and i use the Lambda@Edge to route to B and the request fails, does it route back to A ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. Unless there is something deep within the small print, you won't be charged more. You have to pay for data transfers but you don't need to pay for the storage of what is in the cache.
2. Origin groups dont load balance. They provide a prioritised failover list.

You can use Lambda@Edge dynamiclly route to an origin.

This article covers that.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/

Comment: You can't use a CNAME to refer to an s3 bucket unless the S3 bucket name matches the CNAME. But since bucket names are globally unique you can't latency balance between two buckets using Route53.

Comment: Good point. I was going along the lines of static website hosting but you're totally right. I've updated the answer to remove this.

Comment: @cementblocks I've come to a strategy which is having two separate CloudFront distributions (each serving one of the S3 buckets) and use Route53 to balance (Geo, latency, whatever) the access to the content. Regarding latency on Route 53, how does it measure latency ? viewer -> CF origin (S3) or edge location -> CF origin (S3) or viewer -> edge location ? I wasn't able to find that information ! Thanks for helping out !

Comment: How can you balance between two CloudFront distributions? You can't create two Distributions with the same Alias. Also latency balancing doesn't make much sense because however route53 measures the latency it will be measuring the same values for both distributions because both are globally distributed using the same infrastructure.
What is the latency if you just use a single bucket and single cloudfront distribution?